# What is the difference between deleting package-lock.json + npm install and npm install?

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I'm upgrading dependencies and was wondering why these two workflows don't lead to the same result.

**Option 1** - Delete package-lock.json and npm install.

- Completely upgrades/changes majority of the package-lock.json in addition to the dependencies I upgraded in the package.json
- Source: [https://poanchen.github.io/blog/2020/04/13/how-to-update-package-lock-json-file-in-order-to-honour-the-and-~-symbol](https://poanchen.github.io/blog/2020/04/13/how-to-update-package-lock-json-file-in-order-to-honour-the-and-%7E-symbol)

**Option 2** - Not deleting package-lock.json and npm install

- Upgrades the dependencies in package-lock.json that I changed in the package.json.
- Source: https://betterprogramming.pub/how-to-upgrade-dependencies-in-package-json-e5546804187f

I've searched stackoverflow and no one seems to be asking this.  Can someone please explain the difference between the two and possibly recommend the ideal workflow for upgrading a few dependencies?